# Login does not redirect because of java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

Tags: jsf, indexoutofboundsexception, viewstate

I have a login code that does not direct to xhtml page in to a folder.

This happens when I press for the second time the button to log on to the first one does not execute anything.

```
15:06:45,263 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.context] (default task-1) java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
at javax.faces.component.AttachedObjectListHolder.restoreState(AttachedObjectListHolder.java:146)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.restoreState(UIComponentBase.java:1228)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy$2.visit(FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy.java:372)
at com.sun.faces.component.visit.FullVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(FullVisitContext.java:127)
```

The method I use from action login is, passes to the condition but does not direct to the page:

```
public String actionLogin() {
    try {
        int rolUser = ma.findIdRolByUser(nickname, rol);
        loginConfirm = ma.comprobarUsuario(nickname, clave);
        Mensajes.crearMensajeInfo("Login Correcto");
        if (rolUser == 1) {
            return "Finanzas/dashboard";
        }
        if (rolUser == 2) {
            return "Bodega/dashboard";
        }
        if (rolUser == 3) {
            return "AdminContratos/dashboard";
        }
        if (rolUser == 4) {
            return "Solicitante/dashboard";
        }
        if (rolUser == 5) {
            return "Contabilidad/dashboard";
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Mensajes.crearMensajeError(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}
```

the code in my manager is:

```
public List<UsuarioRol> searchRolUs(String nickname, int idRol) {
    Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT u FROM UsuarioRol u WHERE u.catUsuario.nickname =:nickname"
            + " AND u.catRole.idRol =:idRol");
    q.setParameter("nickname", nickname);
    q.setParameter("idRol", idRol);
    return q.setMaxResults(1).getResultList();
}

    public boolean comprobarUsuario(String nickname, String clave) throws Exception {
    List<UsuarioRol> u = searchUsuario(nickname);
    CatUsuario usuario = new CatUsuario();
    for (UsuarioRol user : u) {
        usuario.setNickname(user.getCatUsuario().getNickname());
        usuario.setClaveUs(user.getCatUsuario().getClaveUs());
        break;
    }
    if (usuario.getNickname() == null)
        throw new Exception("El usuario " + nickname + " no existe");
    if (usuario.getClaveUs().equals(clave)) 
        return true;
    throw new Exception("La clave que ingreso es incorrecta");
}
```

Comment: Please add the full stackTrace and try to reduce the code to be a [mcve]

Comment: ok, I edit this moment

Comment: 1: **Nothing** PrimeFaces related in this question. 2: **No** jsf related code in the question. 3: The stacktrace is only partial. Please take the [tour]  again...

Comment: Javtronic, you're actually not redirecting. You're merely forwarding. You need to append `?faces-redirect=true` to the outcome in order to perform a real redirect. It'll most likely solve your problem.

Comment: @Kukeltje Whilst partial, this stack trace is recognizable as being caused by an incompatible change in the JSF component tree during restore view of the postback as compared to how it was during render response. E.g. because the login button has "unexpectedly" disappeared via a view build time tag such as c:if. This can only be solved by performing a redirect after login. A real redirect :)

Comment: @BalusC: Us mortals would have most likely only be able to find those details by opeining the Mojarra (that I get from the stacktrace ;-)) source and trying to analyse it. Deities on the contrary know those things from the top of their head ;-)

Comment: @BalusC Thx a lot, my eclipse debugger didn't work and I couldn't see the error. I implemented your recommendation and it worked.